# Writing an accessor method for inherited class with sparse member data?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

Say I have a simple vector class, `vec`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class vec {
public:
    vec() {}
    // Constructor.
    vec(int n) {
        len = n;
        data = new double[len];
    }

    // Destructor.
    ~vec() { delete [] data; }

    // Accessor.
    double & operator[](int i) const {
        check_index(i);
        return data[i];
    }

    // Other methods...
    // ....

protected:
    int len;
    double * data;
    void check_index(int i) const {
        if(i < 0 || i >= len) {
            std::cerr << "Bad access.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
};
```

Now suppose I have a special type of `vector` with sparse structure, e.g., where every even-index is zero. Call this `oddvec`. Instances of `oddvec` should be declared just as with the `vec` class, but underneath, the memory use should be efficient since only half the data is non-zero.

The accessor for the `oddvec` class should return 0 if the index is even, and return the odd-index element (stored sequentially) otherwise. There a couple problems with this:

1. The `double &` return type is violated if the index is even, since the constant value, `0`, is returned.
2. It's not clear to me how to handle the situation when an even index element is used as an `lvalue`. E.g., `v[0] = 3.0` should not be allowed in the `oddvec` class, but is perfectly acceptable in the `vector` class. We can't simply throw an error when even indexes are used, because even indexes are fine as long as the intention is as an `rvalue`.

How do I design the accessor function for the `oddvec` class, while both keeping the memory storage efficient and inheriting all the methods from the parent?

Non-working example of `oddvec`:

```
class oddvec : public vec {
public:
    // Constructor.
    oddvec(int n) {
        len = n;
        data = new double[len/2];
    }

    // Accessor (doesn't work!)
    double & operator[](int i) const {
        check_index(i);

        if (i%2 == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return data[(i-1)/2];
    }
};
```

Upon compilation:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘double& oddvec::operator[](int) const’:
main.cpp:49:20: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘double&’ from an rvalue of type ‘double’
             return 0;
```

---

## Working example using proxy classes:

I have implemented a proxy class as suggested in the answer below.

> proxies.h

```
#ifndef PROXIES_H
#define PROXIES_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class proxy {
public:
    proxy(int i, double v, double * d) {
        index = i;
        value = v;
        data  = d;
    }
    void operator=(double rhs) {
        data[index] = rhs;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & outs, const proxy & p) {
        outs << p.value;
        return outs;
    }
protected:
    int     index;
    double  value;
    double * data;
};

class oddproxy : public proxy {
public:
    oddproxy(int i, int v, double * d) : proxy(i, v, d) {}
    void operator=(double rhs) {
        if (index%2 == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Even entries of oddvec are not assignable.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        data[index/2] = rhs;
    }
};

#endif
```

> vectors.h

```
#ifndef VECTORS_H
#define VECTORS_H

#include "proxies.h"

class vec {
public:
    vec() {}
    // Constructor.
    vec(int n) {
        len = n;
        data = new double[len];
    }

    // Destructor.
    ~vec() { delete [] data; }

    // Accessor.
    proxy operator[](int i) const {
        check_index(i);
        return proxy(i, data[i], data);
    }

    inline int length() const { return len; }

    // Other methods...
    // ....

protected:
    int len;
    double * data;
    void check_index(int i) const {
        if(i < 0 || i >= len) {
            std::cerr << "Bad access.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
};


class oddvec : public vec {
public:
    // Constructor.
    oddvec(int n) {
        len = n;
        data = new double[len/2];
    }

    // Accessor.
    oddproxy operator[](int i) const {
        check_index(i);
        return oddproxy(i, (i%2 == 0) ? 0 : data[i/2], data);
    }
};

#endif
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vectors.h"

int main () {
    int N = 5;
    vec V(N);
    oddvec O(N);

    for(int i=0; i < V.length(); i++) {
        V[i] = i;

        if(i%2 != 0) {
            O[i] = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < O.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << "V[" << i << "]=" << V[i] << ", "
                  << "O[" << i << "]=" << O[i] << "\n";
    }

    O[0] = 13;

    return 0;
}
```

> output

```
V[0]=0, O[0]=0
V[1]=1, O[1]=1
V[2]=2, O[2]=0
V[3]=3, O[3]=3
V[4]=4, O[4]=0
Even entries of oddvec are not assignable.
```

Comment: you can return a proxy object (not recommend)

Comment: why (i-1)/2?  how about just i/2 and let the c++ integer division take care of the rounding

Comment: @UKMonkey: Being explicit?

Comment: It's very odd that I can writ `const vec v(10); v[0] = 1.0;` without an error.  I would make the `const` version return by value, and the non-const by reference.

Comment: You also need to make `operator []` be virtual (otherwise if you pass an `oddvec` reference to a function expecting `vec`, it will use the base class version.)

Comment: "Non-working example of oddvec:", what does that mean, does it compile, are you getting erroneous data?

Comment: @MartinBonner, I'll try this, or perhaps you can add as an answer?

Comment: @George, I've edited to add the compilation error. Note that I've defined both classes in a `main.cpp` file with main function, `int main() { return 0; }`

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester if you don't care write-to-even-index operation, you can declare a static variable in somewhere in class and return reference to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proxy object to do this.

---

simple sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class very_odd_vector{
public:
    class only_odd_proxy;
    friend class only_odd_proxy;
    only_odd_proxy operator [](int index);
    int operator [](int index)const{return index%2==0?0:content[index/2];}
    unsigned int size()const{return content.size()*2;}
private:
    vector<int> content{1,3,5,7,9};
};

class very_odd_vector::only_odd_proxy{
public:
   only_odd_proxy(very_odd_vector& vec,int index):vec(vec),index(index){}
   operator int(){return index%2==0 ? 0 : vec.content[index/2];}
   only_odd_proxy& operator =(int value){
      if(index%2==0)
         cout << "BAD OPERATION";//any error you want
      else
         vec.content[index/2] = value;
      return *this;
   }
private:
   very_odd_vector& vec;
   int index;
};

auto very_odd_vector::operator [](int index)->only_odd_proxy{return only_odd_proxy(*this,index);}

int main(){
   very_odd_vector v;

   cout << "reading value\n";
   for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
      cout << v[i] <<'\n';

   cout << "writting value\n";
   for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i){
      cout << i << ':';
      v[i]=10;
      cout << '\n';
   }

   cout << "reading value\n";
   for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
      cout << v[i] <<'\n';
}
```

---

Edit for updated part of question :

I think this class will fit your need more.

```
//Both base and inherit class return this class
class maybe_readonly_proxy {
public:
    maybe_readonly_proxy(double* data, bool readonly):readonly(readonly),data(data){}
    maybe_readonly_proxy& operator=(double rhs) {
        if(readonly){/*whatever error*/}
        else {*data = rhs;}
        return *this;
    }
    operator double()const{return *data;}
private:
    bool readonly;
    double * data;
};
```

You may need a variable to contain readonly (`0` in this case) value, or modify the `operator double()` the check readonly state

---

Or just implement `get` and `set` method separately and do not use this proxy may be another choice.

Comment: 1.  You'd need to add +=/*=/etc.  2.  This would be clearer if it stuck to the vector holding doubles (so `int`s are clearly indices rather than values).  3.  To make this work in the OP's case, the base vector would need to return a proxy too, and the derived class would need to return a proxy which is derived from the base proxy.

Comment: @MartinBonner 1. this is just a simple sample, and i don't want to do all the thing for OP   2. yes, my little mistake, but this is also the chance to check OP knows how this works  3. OP's base class operator[] is not virtual

Comment: @appleapple, nice! Thanks for the suggestion on proxy classes. I've updated my question with a more detailed working example. Is there a reason why you initially said this was not recommended? Also, could would you mind explaining how virtual functions would come into play in my example above? When I add `virtual` to the base class, it fails to compile because the return-type of the derived class does not match the base.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester 1.because in this case, I would like to simply implement `get` and `set` methods, so you will not need to implement all the operations available for `double&` in your `proxy`

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester Answer update for newer part of your question. BTW, modify question so large usually is not good choice, maybe *ask a new question*?

Comment: The main reason that I edited my question was to provide a full, detailed, working example using proxies in **in the context of my original question**, something which future browsers of this question might desire to see, and which was not explicitly present in your answer above. In other words, the sole purpose of my edited question was **not** to facilitate my previous comment about `virtual` functions, but rather to make this Q&A more self-contained. Thanks again.